# Leather straps for practicing tefillin knots

Tags: tefilin, safrus, hekdesh

There are various instructional YouTube videos (such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LSzRf4Lww8), et al), and diagrams (at the end of some Mishnah Berurahs, for instance), that explain how to tie the the various tefillin knots: e.g. Double-dalet, single-dalet, yud, yud (like Chabad), etc.

If one doesn't have spare tefillin straps may they take take their current Shel Rosh, leave the knot as is, and practice making *another* knot from the two retzuos hanging loose below? Is that using kodesh l'chol, the sacred for a non-sacred use?

Not all alternatives have the right thickness for practicing with; strips of cloth are not easy to work with as they flop around.

Comment: Have you tried contacting a sofer/safrus-store? They will probably be willing to sell or even give you a scrap piece of strap that's too short for them to sell for real

Comment: How about leather strap from an arts and crafts store? something like https://www.amazon.com/Leather-Straps-TOFL-Crafts-Strips/dp/B073TM8KTC/ selected at random from Amazon

Comment: Even if using your exisitng straps is permitted (which I'm not commenting on) you should strongly consider using something else for practice to avoid wearing down your own over repeated tying/untying

Comment: Thank you, Double AA - I'll leave my question up, because it's interesting, but I'm getting one from Amazon.